# React - hook state not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, state

I'm trying to copy one form input value to another using state but the state isn't updating

I create a form, with a button, where the value from the left form input should be copied to the right form input. This is my code:

```
const ReviewContactForm = (props) => {
  const contact = props.currentContact;
  const dbContact = useDbContact(contact.Group);
  const [dbSecName, setDbSecName] = useState("");

async function getDbContact() {
    let secName = await dbContact.SecretaryName;
    setDbSecName(secName);
   }
getDbContact();

function acceptSecName(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setDbSecName(contact.SecretaryName);
  }

return (
    <>
        <Form>
          <Form.Row>Secretary's Name</Form.Row>
          <Form.Row>
            <Form.Group as={Col} className="mb-2">
            <Form.Control type="input" name="1secname" value={contact.SecretaryName} readOnly />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group as={Col} className="mb-2">
            <Form.Control type="input" name="2secname" value={dbSecName || ""} readOnly />
            </Form.Group>
            
            <Button className="PrimaryButton" onClick={acceptSecName}>
              Accept proposed
            </Button>
            <div className="divider" />
            <Button className="SecondaryButton" size="sm">
              Revert
            </Button>
          </Form.Row>
        </Form>
    </>
  );
};
```

No matter what I do, the state of dbSecName doesn't change. I've tried setting a new const. I've tried making the onClick function async and await. If I add `console.log` for the value of the variable I'm trying to set to, I see it correctly, but the console.log of dbSecName always shows the original value.

I've not really an idea of what to do next. I'm thinking perhaps my approach to setting the form input in the first place is wrong.

So what I'm trying to achieve is that when the 'Accept proposed' button is clicked, the "2secname" form input is re-rendered with the value from "1secname".

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1):

In the below code snippet

```
<Form.Control type="input" name="2secname" value={dbSecName || ""} readOnly />
```

replace value with just dbSecName instead of `dbSecName || ""`

See if that works

Comment: Unfortunately that adds another issue with a warning "A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled" because the input is re-rendered after this setDbSecName(secName) in the async function. It also doesn't work.

Comment: why are you calling this function `getDbContact();` outside the return body? remove it once and see if it works

Comment: If I do that then the I'm able to call ```acceptSecName``` and the value changes but it means the starting state value is incorrect. Because ```const dbContact = useDbContact(contact.Group)``` comes from an api call. I found the only way to set the value correctly in the first place was to add an async await for the value of ```secName```     see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65233570/react-using-state-to-update-values-or-not

Comment: If on the first render you want to fetch the value from the Api,then better use an useEffect and inside it call the async function.

Comment: Your welcome :) Please mark it as accepted if that helped so that others can also benefit from it :)

Comment: Does it need to be an answer for me to do that?

Comment: No dear,just click on the tick sign present next to my answer :)